# Best way to set unique_together for all fields of a django model

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I would like to prevent the creation of duplicated rows on some tables of my database.
I know one way to do it is setting the [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) or [`constraints`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#constraints)  attribute in the `Meta` class of the model as a tuple with the names of the fields, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do it since my models have 30+ fields, so I don't think it would be practical to repeat the names of them again.

The way I have it now:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  model_id = models.BigAutoField(db_column="MyModelColumnID", primary_key=True)
  field1 = models.BooleanField(...)
  field2 = models.CharField(...)
  field3 = models. ...
  .
  .
  .
  field34 = models. ...
  
  class Meta:
    db_table = "MyTableName"
    unique_together = (
      "field1",
      "field2",
      "field3",
       .
       .
       .
       "field34"
    )
```

I'm looking for something like `unique_together="__all__"` or `all_unique=True`, is this possible on Django?

It is important to me to handle this as a database constraint, the `get_or_create` method won't suffice since it's for an app using multiple threads and making multiple concurrent calls to the database. Thanks !

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no such thing. It is also a bit *odd* that *all* fields are unique together (and that the model has 34 fields). :). Often one can "group" fields together in a separate model (like an `Address` for example that is part of the `Profile`). This results in *reuseable* components.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is just as to not allow duplicate rows on the table. Most of these fields are actually ForeignKeys and other relational fields, and anyway, even if it was 12 fields or 8 I just want to know if there's a way to do it on Django so I don't have to repeat all the fields of the model again.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do what I was looking for but I somehow managed to not repeat all the field names of the model by defining an abstract model and then using that one to get the fields.
Like this:

```
class MyModelBase(models.Model):
  model_id = models.BigAutoField(db_column="MyModelColumnID", primary_key=True)
  field1 = models.BooleanField(...)
  field2 = models.CharField(...)
  field3 = models. ...
  .
  .
  .
  field34 = models. ...
  
  class Meta:
    abstract=True

class MyModel(MyModelBase):

  class Meta:
    db_table = "MyTableName"
    unique_together = tuple(
      [field.name for field in MyModelBase._meta.fields if field.name != "model_id"]
    )
```